# Group email is shows error using php mailer

Tags: php, database, email, phpmailer

Actually I want to send a group mail so I have taken the mail id's from db and stored in the  variable but when I try to send mail using delimeter as 
',' , it shows invalid email id

Below code to Take mail id's from db:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


      $word = $row['Email'];

      $GetData = $GetData.$word.',';

}
```

Now `$GetData =example1@gmail.com,example2@gmail.com`

### php mailer

```
$mail->addAddress$GetData ,user );
```

When I add the same into add address it is not working

> Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Invalid address: (to):example1@gmail.com,example2@gmail.com

Note:
if single id then it is sending successfully , so seems like issue with my side so need assistance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use addAddress for each recipient, you are kind of mixing the old headers style with the new mail object..

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

  $mail->addAddress($row['Email'] , '');

}
```